# Is it possible to access a localhost from a vagrant devbox?

Tags: node.js, localhost, vagrant

I'm running my application on a local Vagrant VM on my computer and I was wondering if I created a node server that ran on localhost (also on my computer) would I be able to access the node server from my Vagrant application ?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

With default vagrant settings, you can reach your host computer via the IP `10.0.2.2`. This is at least true for the VirtualBox provider. I haven't tested others so far.

If you have configured your node server on the host machine in way that it listens to *all* IP addresses assigned to your host computer you should be able to access

```
http://10.0.2.2
```

from within the vagrant virtual machine.

Comment: When using Parallels with Vagrant `http://10.211.55.2` should work from within the Vagrant virtual machine.